# What kind of insulation to use against cinderblock after repair?

Tags: insulation, cinderblock

I needed to replace an old outside spigot, and to get proper access to the pipe inside the walls, I had to remove a lot of old and very crumbly insulation.  I'm not sure what kind of insulation it is, but my house was built in 1977, so I'll send a sample off to be tested for asbestos.

[image]

The old insulation is unusable, and frankly I wouldn't want to keep it in my house even if I could.  But that leaves me unsure what kind of insulation I should put against the cinderblock.  I suppose I could get spray foam.  I'm not crazy at the idea of something adhering to the cinderblock, because the cinderblock is pretty clean everywhere else in the house.  It's my understanding that foam board needs be installed without gaps, or the temperature differentials may promote condensation and mold growth.

[image]

Under different circumstances, I would probably try batt insulation, but my access is limited, so I'm not sure I would be able to secure it properly behind the vent, for example.  And there's still four of five linear feet of the old stuff above the opening, currently being held up by some cardboard that I wedged under it.  I'm not sure what to replace that cardboard with, because the stuff is all so crumbly—it just turns into powder when touched.

With the luxury of more time, I would probably open up the wall further, remove all of the old insulation, clean everything up, and figure out the best insulation to use, but I don't have that luxury.  What kind of insulation is recommended for something like this in northern Virginia?

Comment: That looks like AB foam / poly spray foam. I'd consider replacing it with similar given the limited access. It was pretty early for those foams in 1977. They never contained asbestos. My parents house was built in 1981 and uses a bunch of it. It works great.

Comment: When all was said and done, I concluded that the insulation was not original to the house, and that I probably caused it myself when trying to seal a gap around a light fixture.  Since the rest of the house seemed not to have insulation, and since the HVAC vent would warm that space in the winter, I figured there was no danger to the spigot or its pipe.  And I shut off and drain that pipe further inside in wintertime.